# Is $3^{1/2}+3^{1/3}+3^{1/4}+3^{1/5}+\cdots+3^{1/(n+1)}$ always irrational?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers

> $$3^{1/2}+3^{1/3}+3^{1/4}+3^{1/5}+\cdots+3^{1/(n+1)}$$
> where $n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Is this always irrational?
>
> If it is always irrational, how can we prove it?

I am second year student of mathematics I know calculus 1+2+3 ,ODES,logic and writing proofs . at my current semester I am studying Abstract Algebra 01 ,Number Theory , Real Analysis ,PDES 01 and Linear Algebra 01.
This question comes to my mind while I am thinking about the uncountability of irrationals

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122975/discussion-on-question-by-mahmoud-albahar-is-31-231-331-431-5-c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $N=\operatorname{lcm}(2,3,\ldots,n+1)$. Observe that $N$ is even, and that one of the indices $2,3,\ldots,n+1$, is divisible by the same power of two as $N$. Let $\alpha=3^{1/N}$ be the real and positive $N$th root of $3$. The sum, denote it by $\Sigma$, is an element of the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Roadmap: Describe a non-trivial automorphism $\sigma$ of $K$. Show that $\Sigma$ is not a fixed point of $\sigma$. Conclude.

Comment: Posting a coarse hint with a view of inducing a dialogue with the asker, and getting them to edit the question into shape. I tried to fine-tune the level of detail in such a way that the hint is useless unless they know enough.

Comment: Hope the question is updated at least with their background.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another proof, which I consider simpler. Following Jyrki Lahtonen we let $N=\mathrm{lcm}(2,3...n+1)$, $\alpha=3^{1/N}$, and $\Sigma$ be the sum in question. Moreover, let

$$\Sigma(x)=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}x^{N/k}=\mathrm{degree\,\,}N/2\,\,\mathrm{polynomial}$$

Which has $\Sigma(\alpha)=\Sigma$. Thus, the polynomial $\Sigma(x)-\Sigma$ has degree $N/2$ and $\alpha$ is a root, which is a contradiction since we know that $p(x)=x^{N}-3$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's criterion so $\deg(\alpha)=N$. Q.E.D, no automorphisms needed.

Comment: Yes, this is most certainly simpler than mine! Well done! I did upvote this back in April, but forgot to comment.

Comment: Many thanks to you, my knowledge level now is sufficient to understand your answer but barely even after one year and eight months, but What are good resources for algebraic numbers?

Comment: We can apply Eisenstein's criterion with prime 3.